# The image had 0kb size is created from taskpicture function and GallerySaver function flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, camera

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhdWW.png)> The image size was 0kb in the Pictures folder. but I could open from album in devices. I read logs and found "Access denied finding property "persist.camera.cfa.packagelist" maybe I missed permission. Could you tell me, I should use what permission?
I registed

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> 

void _takePicture(BuildContext context) async {
try {
  await _initializeCameraControllerFuture;

  final directory = Platform.isAndroid
      ? await getExternalStorageDirectory()
      : await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  final filename = '${DateTime.now()}.jpg';
  await new Directory(directory.path).create(recursive: true);

  final path = join(directory.path, filename);
  await _cameraController.takePicture(path);
  bool save = await GallerySaver.saveImage(path);
  print(save);
  print(path);
  Navigator.pop(context, path);
} catch (e) {
  print('error $e');
}
```

}

Comment: I'm sure it permission problem. Surround `await new Directory(directory.path).create(recursive: true);` this piece of code in a try block. and print the error.   `try{ await new Directory(directory.path).create(recursive: true);}catch(e){print(e.toString();}`  Update us after that

Comment: yes I'm sure. I could show the image in other view "Navigator.pop..." my function is running successfully. However I existed my app, I could not find it in the gallery on device

Comment: You can show it because that's in your app memory currently.  Once you close the app and then you can see that again. Then it's fine

Comment: but after close app ... not found. I checked your suggest, it had no error appear

Comment: You need to save it to the gallery.

Add https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver. Then use GallerySaver.saveImage(path);

Comment: But image is created had 0 kb size in directory folder(at here Pictures folder)